# How do I easily get the Phoenix Blaster?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria I can't find a Phoenix Blaster in dungeons. I have made 3 world's with dungeons but can't find one in a chest. Is there a reason or another easier way? I need it to kill the WoF.

Answer (score 6):

The [Phoenix Blaster](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phoenix_Blaster) is crafted, not found. You can craft it at an [Iron Anvil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Iron_Anvil) with a [Handgun](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Handgun) and 10 [Hellstone Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone_Bar).

You can make [Hellstone Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone_Bar) at a [Hellforge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellforge) with 3 [Hellstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone) and 1 [Obsidian](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian) each. In order to mine [Hellstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone) and [Obsidian](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian), you'll need a [Nightmare Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe), a [Deathbringer Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Deathbringer_Pickaxe), or a [Reaver Shark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Reaver_Shark).